# How can I test Rack middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, logging, couchdb, rack

I'm writing a middleware that does something like this

```
Given I am logged in
When I visit home page
Then the request and all of my user information should get logged into CouchDB
```

This is basically it, the middleware itself isn't that complicated, but I'm having trouble with the workflow.

First thing is, that I have no idea how to test something like this. The feature itself is pretty clear, but how would I go about implementing it? Probably the highest level test that I can do is send a request via `curl` and then check if it got saved into CouchDB.

The problem is, I'm not really sure at what level should I test this and what types of tests will be most helpful. At the moment I basically hit F5 and take a look in the db if there is a new record.

The app is running on Rails 3.2.2 and I'm using `couchrest` gem to do the logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the place for integration tests. If the stock rails integration tests bypass your middleware treat it like a rack app and use [ https://github.com/brynary/rack-test ]

Answer (score 1):

This Sinatra tutorial ought to help:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html

You probably also want to redirect logging for your middleware to the Rails logger in an initializer so you can see what's going on while your tests are running:

`My::Awesome::Middleware.logger = Rails.logger`